# logged in username on a web app incorrect when site live

Tags: visual-studio

I've got a web app that runs on a machine and should only be used if a particular user is logged on to that machine.  so in page_load I have the following code:

```
    dim sName as string = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName
    if sName <> 'sstation' then
       Response.Direct("NoAccess.aspx")
    end if
```

this works perfectly when I am in Visual Studio debugging, if I am logged on to the computer as sstation, the page loads up, if not it loads the NoAccess page.  However, if I open the page in a web browser, it always takes me to the NoAccess page and I can't figure out why! Any ideas

I've added a text box to the page and added this code:

```
    lblErrorMessage.Text = "You are logged in as " + sADname
```

and the name comes up as Administrator even though I am logged on to the machine as sstation, so where does System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName come from when the page is on a server?

Answer (score 0):

This code is running on the web server, NOT the machine that the user is logged in to.  It will return the user account that IIS is running as.  The reason it works on your local machine when debugging is that the web server is running on your local machine in that case.  This account can be configured in the `App Pool` that the IIS site is set to use.  See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx) link for more information on configuring it.

In order to get the user account of the client machine in IIS, IIS will have to be configured for `Windows authentication`, and both the client and server will most likely need to be part of a `Domain`.  If that isn't possible you will need to use some other kind of authentication, the easiest being `Forms` authentication, or `ASP.NET Identity`.

Here are some links to get you started.

- [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)
- [Forms Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx)
- [Windows Authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx)